# Creating a empty array to be passed into a function . Using Arm Assembly

Tags: arrays, assembly, parameters, segmentation-fault, arm

Hello I am trying to create an array of 3 indexes that will be filled by a function that I pass it into.

```
@ r4 contains length
sub sp, sp, #12     @ allocate 3 indexes for NEW array
mov r3, #4       @ r3 = 4
mul sp, sp, r3   @ sp = (# array elements)*4
mov r0, r4       @ r0 = r4 = length parameter
mov r1, sp       @ r1 = (sp*index number) len[0] parameter
bl convert2pixel @ convert2pixel(length, len)
```

Something is incorrect about this. because i keep segfaulting when i branch to convert2pixel

Convert2Pixel C Code:

```
void convert2pixel(int length, unsigned char len[3])
{
        // byte3-byte2-byte1
    unsigned char byte1, byte2, byte3;

        byte1 = (unsigned char)(length % 256);
        byte2 = (unsigned char)((length >> 8) % 256);
        byte3 = (unsigned char)((length >> 16) % 256);

        len[0] = byte1;
        len[1] = byte2;
        len[2] = byte3;
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what you want `mul sp, sp, r3` to do. You have already allocated the space, you should not move the stack pointer any more. Also `r4` is not initialized.

Comment: convert2pixel uses the 3 indexes. How else could i get it to be able to cycle through the array without changing the convert2pixel function.
r4 contains length from prior code.

Comment: You should remove that `mul` there is no point to it. You should however restore the stack before you return from your function. You should also make sure `lr` is preserved.

Comment: Okay! Will len[1] in c mean that it moves to that next location in the array?

Comment: `len[1]` is `*(sp+1)`

Comment: Then how do i get it to *4 to get to the right index

Comment: You seem to be seriously confused about something. `unsigned char len[3]` is just 3 consecutive bytes in memory. That's all.

Comment: I wouldn't be asking here if i wasn't confused.